# Can we use DispatcherTimer within a BackgroundWorker?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have got some WPF application. I need to execute some code  within a `BackgroundWorker`  and I use `DispatcherTimer` for that. Also that code doesn't use UI.

My question is it OK like that? Or it is better to use `Timer` or `while` & `Thread.Sleep`?

Also is it better to use `Task` & `Timer` or `DispatcherTimer` instead of `BackgroundWorker`?

So we have 2 approaches to choose. (Or more?)

1. `BackgroundWorker` calls `DispatcherTimer || Timer || (While & Thread.Sleep)`
2. `Task`  calls `DispatcherTimer || Timer || (While & Thread.Sleep)`

**I just need to know the best performance solution.**

Here is some code

```
DispatcherTimer logManagerUpdater = new DispatcherTimer(DispatcherPriority.Background);
BackgroundWorker logManagerWorker = new BackgroundWorker();

private void StartLogManager()
{
    logManagerWorker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(logManagerWorker_DoWork);
    logManagerWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
}

void logManagerWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.logManagerWorker.CancellationPending)
    {
       e.Cancel = true;
       return;
    }

    logManagerUpdater.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10);
    logManagerUpdater.Tick += new EventHandler(logManagerUpdater_Tick);  
    logManagerUpdater.Start();
}

void logManagerUpdater_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   LogManagerJob();   
   LogDBManagerJob();  
}
```

Comment: You say you're using `DispatcherTimer` *within* a `BackgroundWorker`?  You'd better post some code...

Comment: @DanPuzey Sorry the code is too big. I just need to know the best performance solution.

Comment: @DanPuzey I just put some code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your code doesn't use the UI then `DispatcherTimer` is unnecessary - it's specifically there to fire code *on the Dispatcher thread* (usually the UI thread).  A regular timer is enough.

Moreover, in your posted code, you're essentially "creating a background thread to create a background thread."   I would suggest that you remove the background worker entirely, and just create the timer in your `StartLogManager` method.